# displaying the opencv window on top Qt(c++) dialogs/widgets

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl0d7.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksbgI.png)

I am new to Qt. I am developing a Qt(c++) and opencv application on Ubuntu 14.

My application has three Qt diaglog windows.The 2nd dialog opens by pressing the pushbutton on the first dialog. The 3rd dialog opens by pressing the pushbutton on the 2nd dialog.

In the 3rd dialog on the press of a push button i do some image processing operations using opencv and display the results using opencv function namedWindow.  This is shown in image1

The problem is the opencv windows("source" and "centers") are not displayed on top of the 3 qt dialogs. This is shown in image2

How do i display the opencv windows on top of all the qt dialogs and have complete access to the opencv window to perform operations like clicking on pixels, rectangular selection , thresholding using scroll bar(basically mouse call back) on the opencv window.

Please help me out with this problem

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Hi and welcome, if I understood yor question correct you need to integrate the OpenCV image in a QWidget. There was a pretty good article on this some time ago [OpenCV Qt Widget](http://develnoter.blogspot.de/2012/05/integrating-opencv-in-qt-gui.html)

Comment: @ sts  , Thanks for the reply. I have added 2 image to explain it clearly. In the image1 you can see that the two opencv windows ("source" and "centers") are displayed . But when i try to move them on top of the qt windows i cant bring the opencv windows to the foreground and keep the qt dialogs in the background. How do i bring the 2 opencv windows to the foreground?